# Fio Replay of Blktrace File Fails due to No Space Left on the Device

Tags: io, trace

I am using fio-3.14 to replay a trace file created by blktrace. My linux version is Mint 18.3 with the kernel 4.10.0-38-generic. As a root, I followed the steps as below:

1. First Step

I applied an fio workload on the /home/arghavan/fio/test with the following workload options. At the same time, I used the command: `blktrace -d /dev/sda6`, to capture traces on /dev/sda6 since it is mounted on /home where fio is running the workload.

**Fio Workload**

```
; Read 4 files with aio at different depths
[global]
ioengine=libaio
directory=/home/arghavan/fio/test

buffered=0
rw=randread
bs=128k
size=512m


[file1]
iodepth=4

[file2]
iodepth=32

[file3]
iodepth=8

[file4]
iodepth=16
```

2. Second Step

I used the command: `blkparse sda6 -a read -o /dev/null -d /root/traces/sda6_trace.bin` to make blkparse binary file with which fio can replay the trace.

3. Third Step

I used fio with the command: `fio --name=rp1 --read_iolog=/home/arghavan/traces/sda6_trace.bin --replay_no_stall=1 --replay_redirect=/dev/sda6` to replay the trace. However, the fio reports the following error:

```
fio: io_u error on file /dev/sda6: No space left on device: write offset=278643662848, buflen=4096
fio: pid=11495, err=28/file:io_u.c:1785, func=io_u error, error=No space left on device
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [f(1)][-.-%][eta 00m:00s]
rp1: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err=28 (file:io_u.c:1785, func=io_u error, error=No space left on device)
```

There is a lot of space avilable on this device and I don't know what the problem is. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `blktrace` only recorded I/O for `/dev/sda6` partition and didn't quitely record I/O for the whole of `/dev/sda` instead? I see https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrace/msg00417.html but I'm not sure if it ever was applied to the mainstream kernel...